# Simple Javascript Slider

Tags: javascript, slider

Im trying to find a very very simple javascript slider. 
One that is the bare minimum, no fancy jquery, or other libraries involved.
The simplest possible slider. With the minimum amount of code possible.

Thanks for the attention!

@ Roger Walsh:

Below the HTML code:
The .js and the .css are identical to the example in the tutorial you send me. 
I guess I have to add some more info in the body section, but I dont understand what exactly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<html>
<head>

<title> Slider </title> 

<script type="JavaScript" src="slider.js"></script>
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<html>
<head>

<title> </title> 
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="carpe_slider_display_holder">
<!-- Default value: 0 -->
<input class="carpe_slider_display" id="display1" type="text" value="100" />
</div>
<div class="carpe_horizontal_slider_track">

    <div class="carpe_slider_slit"> </div>
    <div class="carpe_slider" id="my_id" orientation="horizontal" distance="100" display="my_id" style="left: 100px;"> </div>
</div>

<!--<div class="carpe_horizontal_slider_track">
    <div class="carpe_slider_slit"> </div>
    <div class="carpe_slider"
        id="my_id"
        orientation="horizontal"
        distance="100"
        display="my_id"
        style="left: 100px;"> </div>
</div>
-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no very simple slider is possible without those libraries. You would have to write different code for different browsers, that handle events. Why are you so unwilling to use 3rd party libraries?

Comment: I am not unwilling. I just want to understand how that works from a simple slider.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to code less and in quick time, I will recommend you to use an existing library for this.

Look at [dhtmlx Slider](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSlider/index.shtml)

[Simplest Slider Example](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSlider/samples/01_init/03_slider_init_input.html)

Answer (score 1):

The Carpe Slider is now at version 3.0, and there is documentation here: http://carpe.ambiprospect.com/slider/documentation.htm and a test page: http://carpe.ambiprospect.com/slider/test.htm

The js code is 4 kB compressed.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This would have been better as a comment to the accepted answer. But since you're new you can't comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

http://carpe.ambiprospect.com/slider/

Comment: Nice thanks a lot! I am just trying to make it work. I did everything in the tutorial. But for some reason the slider displays but does not move. What can I have forgotten? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJx8k/7/)

**JS:**

```
//init
slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
containerWidth = 500;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(slides, function (el, i) {//set the initial position of each slide
  el.style.left = (i * containerWidth) + "px";
});

window.moveSlides = function (direction) {
  run = true;
  tracker = containerWidth; //500 in this example. We make a separate variable so we can decrement it

  if (((direction == "next" && (parseInt(slides[0].style.left) <= (0 - (containerWidth * (slides.length - 1)))))) //compare against 2nd-to-last slide's index, otherwise it'll go 1 slide too far
     || (direction == "prev" && (parseInt(slides[0].style.left) >= 0))) { run = false; }

  if (run) {
    var slideInterval = setInterval(function () {
      moveRate = 4; //set the speed here (use numbers that the container's width can be divided by without a remainder)
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(slides, function (el, i) {
          if (tracker <= 0) {
             clearInterval(slideInterval)
          } else {
            el.style.left = (direction == "next") ? (parseInt(el.style.left) - moveRate) + "px" : (parseInt(el.style.left) + moveRate) + "px";
          }
        });
        tracker -= moveRate;
    }, 1);
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider-container">
  <div id="slider-mask">
     <div class="slide one">slide 1</div>
     <div class="slide two">slide 2</div>
     <div class="slide three">slide 3</div>
     <div id="buttons">
       <a href="javascript:moveSlides('prev');" id="prev">&lt;Previous</a>
       | 
       <a href="javascript:moveSlides('next');" id="next">Next&gt;</a>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slider-container {
  width: 999999px;
  height: 300px; //set to the height you want
  position:relative;
}
#slider-mask {
  width:500px;  //set slide width. must be equal to slide width
  height:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.slide {
  width:500px;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  position:absolute;
}
#buttons {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:5px;
  left:50%;
  width: 150px;
  height:30px;
  margin-left:-75px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could create a simple slider with `Javascript` and `JQuery`. this slider can go to next or previous slide with fading effect and has a pair of buttons for controling it
(i used some free photo links and `JQuery` cdn so maybe they change):

```js
const box = $('.slider-box');
const children = box.children();
// a List of every slide object
var list = [];

$(document).ready(() => {

    children.each(function () {
        // Add the object of every slide
        list.push($(this));
    });

    children.each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active-slide') === false) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    })
})

// Interval work variables
let timer = '';
var index = 1;
let status = 'after';

const sliderStart = () => {
    timer = setInterval(() => {

        // If its the first index, hide the last index
        if (index === 0) {
            list[list.length - 1].hide();
        } else {

            list[index - 1].hide();
        }

        // Show element
        list[index].fadeIn();
        index += 1;

        // If index is equal list length change to 0
        if (index === list.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }, 3000);
}

// To start automatically
sliderStart();

function next() {
    status = 'after';
    // console.log('Index is: ' + String(index));
    clearInterval(timer);

    // Hide the current slide
    if (index === 0) {
        list[list.length-1].hide();
    } else {
        list[index-1].hide();
    }

    // Show next slide
    list[index].fadeIn();

    // Show the next slide and index+
    if (0 <= index && index < list.length-1) {
        index += 1;
    } else if (index === list.length-1) {
        index = 0;
    }

    sliderStart();
}

function previous() {
    status = 'previous';
    // console.log('Index is: ' + String(index));
    clearInterval(timer);

    // Get the current slide index
    if (index === 0) {
        index = list.length-1;
    } else {
        index -= 1;
    }

    // Hide the current slide
    list[index].hide();

    // Show the last slide
    if (0 < index && index <= list.length-1) {
        list[index-1].fadeIn();
    } else if (index === 0) {
        list[list.length-1].show();
    }

    sliderStart();

}
```

```css
div, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.slider-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}

.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.number {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 500%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simple-slider</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>

    <div class="slider-box">
        <div class="slide active-slide" id="slide1" style="background-color: blue">
            <div class="number">1</div>
            <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/painting-mountain-lake-with-mountain-background_188544-9126.jpg?w=2000">
        </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide2" style="background-color: red">
            <div class="number">2</div>
            <img src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/beautiful-landscape-with-high-mountains-lagoon-water-with-sunlight-golden-sunrise_143683-8450.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide3" style="background-color: rgb(94, 235, 89)">
            <div class="number">3</div>
            <img src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/man-stands-field-with-mountains-background_808092-6114.jpg?w=360">
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <button onclick="next()">next</button>
    <button onclick="previous()">previous</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   I’ve been using this component for my projects:

 <html>
    <script src="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />
    
    <div id="slider">
        <img src="https://jsuites.net/templates/default/img/car.jpeg"/>
        <img src="https://jsuites.net/templates/default/img/car2.jpeg"/>
        <img src="https://jsuites.net/templates/default/img/car3.jpeg"/>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    
    <button id="open-slider" type="button" class="jbutton dark">Open the slider</button>
    
    <script>
    jSuites.slider(document.getElementById('slider'), {
        grid: true
    });
    
    document.getElementById('open-slider').addEventListener('click', function() {
        slider.open();
    });
    </script>
    </html>

It’s helped a lot!
```

https://jsuites.net/docs/image-slider